# Integral Test Proof

Tags: calculus

> [image]
>   [image]

Could someone explain what does it mean by "(and hence $\sum a_n$)"?

Isn't $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ for all $n$? How does the convergence of $\sum a_{n+1}$ imply $\sum a_n$ converges when we have $\sum a_{n+1} \leq \sum a_n$

Comment: It's the same series, almost. Write them both down and see...

Comment: They arent' the same. $\sum a_{n+1}$ contains one more term

Comment: That's why I said "almost". Would adding one extra term affect convergence?

Comment: Oh wait, they are summing up to infinity...my argument fails.

Comment: @DavidMitra, don't you mean removing one term?

Comment: You have to add $a_1$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}$ ($=a_2+a_3+\cdots$) to get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

Comment: Oh we are starting at $n = 1$. I didn't notice that (evident by my lack of indices in my question).

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell me which analysis book you are using, I'm currenlty searching one.

Comment: its Spivak's calculus book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sums differ only by the term $a_1$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=a_1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}\;.$$

If one of them converges, the other must as well. If you want to be a bit more rigorous about it, look at the sequences of partial sums. If the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}$ are $s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots$, then the partial sums of the original series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ are $a_1+s_1,a_1+s_2,a_1+s_3,\dots\;$. If the first sequence of partial sums converges to $L$, then the second converges to $a_1+L$. If the first diverges, so does the second.

Comment: You forgot $a_1$ on the right hand side of your equations

Comment: Why can't we pick a term in the middle? Why $a_1$? Or did you do that simply because it is easier to write the summations?

Comment: Ah okay I like your rigorous argument.

Comment: @sidht: In fact you could drop out or change any finite number of terms, and the resulting series would have the same convergence properties as the original one: either both converge, or both diverge. But the two about which you asked happen to differ only by the presence or absence of the term $a_1$, so I just talked about that case.